# Continue to refresh while sheet has values

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all I'm trying to figure out how to make the sheet refresh until there are no more value errors (#Value, #Err-User Err).

If you do it manually it usually takes 3 refreshes, but due to their being bloomberg formulas in it, the wait time inbetween refreshes can vary. Once it is done and there are no value errors it would move to the macro to publish it - below is what I have so far (obviously a beginner to vba), would appreciate any help on this.

```
while bool in Range("C23:BQ264"):
    Sheets("SOFR Close").Calculate
    Call addrow
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE IN A MODULE

```
Option Explicit

'GLOBAL VARIABLE - HOLDS THE TIME TO RUN THE TIMER SUB "check_errors_timer"
Public nextTimerTime As Date
Public ERROR_TIMER_CNT as Long

' This Sub searches for cells with errors in the specified range. 
' If found then the code that will eliminate them is executed. 
' If VBA is busy, nothing is executed, but the timer Sub is set 
' to reexecute in one second. Sub is continuously re-executed until 
' there are no cells with errors in that range.

'change the SHEET17 with your sheet 
Public Sub check_errors_timer()
   Dim errRng As Range
   If ERROR_TIMER_CNT > 0 Then Exit Sub
   On Error Resume Next
   Set errRng = SHEET17.Range("C23:BQ264").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   If Not errRng Is Nothing Then
      ERROR_TIMER_CNT = ERROR_TIMER_CNT + 1
      If Application.ready Then
         'HERE YOUR CODE TO ELIMINATE THE ERRORS
               'Sheets("SOFR Close").Calculate
               'Call addrow
      End If
Lerr:
      On Error GoTo 0
      ERROR_TIMER_CNT = ERROR_TIMER_CNT - 1
      nextTimerTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
      Application.OnTime nextTimerTime, "check_errors_timer"
   Else
      nextTimerTime = 0
   End If
End Sub

'helper sub to stop the timer 
Public Sub stop_error_timer()
   If nextTimerTime = 0 Then Exit Sub
   Do
      DoEvents
      If ERROR_TIMER_CNT <= 0 Then Exit Do
   Loop
   Application.OnTime nextTimerTime, "check_errors_timer", , Schedule:=False
   nextTimerTime = 0
End Sub
```

THIS SUB IN THE SHEET'S MODULE. INITIATE THE TIMER SUB

```
Sub initiateCheckErrorsTimer()
   Call check_errors_timer
End Sub
```